# search-engine-client npm module working locally but not after firebase function deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-functions

Cloud function is working locally, but after deployment stops working.

The purpose is to get links from the search engines for a specific query to later seek inside each page for specific information.

I´ve tried in heroku, but also it´s not working.

## index.js

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const credential = require('./xxx-firebase-adminsdk-xxx-xxx.json')
    const sec = require('search-engine-client');
    
    console.log('initialing functions at ', new Date().toString())
        
        admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(credential), databaseURL: "https://wasender-fa4c9.firebaseio.com" });
    
    exports.getLinks = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onCall((data, context) => {
    
      console.log('starting to get links ', new Date().toString())
    
      console.log('search-engine-client working? ', sec)
    
    
    sec.google("text to search").then(function(result){
        console.log('google result',result); // these lines are not getting printed in the function log
    });
    
    
    sec.bing("text to search").then(function(result){
        console.log('bing result',result); // these lines are not getting printed in the function log
    });


    })
```

It´s not printing any of the result links for the search engines.

## Log

```
search-engine-client working?  { google: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  bing: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  aol: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  ask: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  yahoo: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  duckduckgo: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  baidu: [AsyncFunction: GetLinks],
  builder: [AsyncFunction: LinkBuilder] }
```

Full code available at pastebin: https://pastebin.com/aCRJrFk5

## Edited

I´ve found that nightmare.js and electron would run only on Aws and on Azure. I´m trying now to deploy it on azure.

Aparently because Nightmare.js uses Electron, it requires a operating system with graphical user interface. Otherwise doesn´t work. A VPS could be the solution for this case.